# Is there any way of setting a value for datetime field in ListInstance

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-listtemplate

I am creating a feature that declares a custom list template and a list instance from this template. Also, ListInstance contains several rows with default data and in my content type there's a DateTime field with DateTimeFormat set to DateTime.

The part with DateTime field in ListInstance looks like follows:

```
<Row>
  <Field Name="MyOtherField"></Field>
  <Field Name="MyDateTimeField">2011-12-30T21:00:00.0000000Z</Field>
  <Field Name="MyIntField">0</Field>
</Row>
```

When I am trying to activate a feature, if shows me the following error:
The element 'MyListInstance' of type 'ListInstance' for feature 'MyFeature' (id: GUID) threw an exception during activation: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Was trying to use local datetime format (en-US) or ISO 8601 format - no luck so far.

So the question is - what datetime format to use when I need to define DateTime field value in ListInstance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
<Row>
  <Field Name="MyOtherField"></Field>
  <Field Name="MyDateTimeField">2011-12-30T21:00:00Z</Field>
  <Field Name="MyIntField">0</Field>
</Row>
```

I have a Feature that has loaded a Date field using that format.

Comment: SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime converts DateTime param to strings in this format - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility_methods.aspx